# Laravel 4 how to add user id as a default value when inserting new records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am building app for enterprise

their are three table:
1- users table (belong to company)
2- companies table (has many users)
3- branches table (belong to company)

when adding a branch I want to pass the company id in the model by default by adding the following code to the branches model

```
 protected $attributes = array(
    'company_id' => Auth::user()->company->id,
 );
```

this will reduce the hassle of inserting company_id for each insert or update of a record

Comment: You can't define properties that rely on runtime information in PHP `This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated. `, try setting it in your constructor

Comment: thanks, yeah i think this explains why my previews solution was not working, many  thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the save method of your Model:

```
class YourModelClass extends Eloquent {

    public function save(array $options = array())
    {
        if( ! $this->company_id)
        {
            $this->company_id = Auth::user()->company->id;
        }

        parent::save($options);
    }

}
```

Not everytime you do:

```
$model = new YourModelClass;
$model->name = 'a name';
$mode->save();
```

It will also add the company_id to that model

Comment: Thanks this worked after tweaking your code to the following   public function save(array $options = array())
 {
  if( ! $this->company_id)
        {
            $this->company_id = Auth::user()->company->id;
        }
     parent::save($options);
 }

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right! Just edited it. Glad you got the idea :)

Comment: I think you  have to pass $options to save parent::save($options);